# Assigning label colour in ggplot based on condition returns unexpected (and incorrect) results

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Really strange thing going on, where if I try to assign the colour of the axis label based on a condition being met, the plot returned has axis labels coloured that do not match the criteria.

For example

```
 p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = ifelse(mtcars$cyl==4, "red", "black"), angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Returns a box plot where "8" is labelled red, and "4" and "6" are black. However if I set the condition that is not true in any of the cases eg:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = ifelse(mtcars$cyl=="something", "red", "black"), angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

All labels are black.

If I choose a condition that they all meet, they are all red, eg:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = ifelse(mtcars$cyl < 100, "red", "black"), angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Yet anything where only some meet the criteria, I get random results.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = ifelse(mtcars$cyl < 5, "red", "black"), angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

returns only 8 as red, and

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = ifelse(mtcars$cyl < 7, "red", "black"), angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

returns all of them as red.

Does anyone know what's going on?! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that your input data contains many elements, while the scale contains only three elements, corresponding to the levels of your data.

Thus you have to pass a vector to `scale_x_discrete` of length 3, not the length of your data.

```
breaks <- levels(as.factor(mtcars$cyl))
colours <- ifelse(breaks == 4, "red", "blue")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete("Cyl", breaks = breaks) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = colours, size = 16))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `ifelse` is checking against the whole `mtcars$cyl` vector, which has values:

```
`[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4`
```

Therefore, it returns the values (for the first example):

```
 [1] "black" "black" "red"   "black" "black" "black" "black" "red" "red" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "black" "red"  

[19] "red"   "red"   "red"   "black" "black" "black" "black" "red"   "red"   "red"   "black" "black" "black" "red"
```

And then the `element_text` `color` parameter uses them in order.  It's not doing what you expect, which is checking the values of `x` on the axis.  To do that, generate the colors in a separate step and then pass them to the `element_text` parameter (Which @Andrie has done nicely in the other answer).